# SSH Internet Connection

Tags: raspbian, internet

I have my raspberry pi connected to my router and a laptop also connected to the router. I can SSH to the pi from the laptop perfectly. However, when I try to install something it says "`connection to host failed [my router's ip address 80]`". When I try to ping google I get a 100% packet loss rate.

My Ethernet light is blinking as if data were being transmitted though and when I run `ifup eth0` i get a message saying its already configured. My `resolv.conf` file has my router's ip as a nameserver and my interfaces file is set up for `dhcp`. `ifconfig` shows my eth0 with an IP of 192.168.0.9.

This is a fresh install of Minibian(basically Rasbian but without extra features.) I also tried it with Rasbian and had the same issue. What could the issue be?

Comment: With ethernet, the most unequivocal way check whether the problem is on the pi or elsewhere is by running a packet sniffer such as [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on some other computer also on the same ethernet LAN (it's also possible on wifi, but there are complications).  If that system can see the packets going out, then they went out -- the problem is not the pi.  If it didn't, then it is.  By way of explanation: all transmissions on a wired subnet are visible to *all* nodes on that subnet, always.

Comment: Are you sure the IP of your nameserver is the same as the IP of your router?  If so, that should not be; your router is almost certainly not a nameserver.  When you say pinging google fails, is that using `google.com`, or an actual IP address?

Comment: OK...I really have no idea what a nameserver is but yes the ip in resolv.conf and the ip of my router currently are the same. When I ping I tried the commands, `ping www.google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8`. Both started the ping command which I Ctrl c'ed after a couple of seconds and it said so many packets failed.

Comment: I guess the router could be set up to forward to your ISP's actual nameservers, I dunno all the possible schemes there.  But pinging an IP address doesn't require a nameserver, so that does imply you have no inet.  What about pinging the router?

Comment: Ok, Ill try that.

Comment: Pinging the router gave a 0 percent packet loss! It worked. So what does that tell us?

Comment: That your router is blocking the pi.  You could confirm this via wireshark while pinging anything -- if you can see that elsewhere on the LAN, the pi did everything it could do.

Comment: If you have a 2nd computer to run wireshark on, you could certainly do simpler testing such as pinging the RPi, verifying the 2nd computer can access the Internet and so forth. Wireshark may not do much good if the OP is using a switch. If the RPi can ping the router's inside IP address, confirm that the default gateway is set properly on the RPi with `ip route`. You should see a `default via <your router IP>`. If not, you can't route traffic off the local subnet. Your router could be denying NAT translation for the RPi, but if other comp's work, it's probably OK.

Comment: You should post the output of `ifconfig` on the Pi, and the equivalent on your laptop.

Comment: `eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:0c:51:73  
          inet addr:192.168.0.9  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:36888 (36.0 KiB)  TX bytes:91977 (89.8 KiB)`

Comment: `lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:200 (200.0 B)  TX bytes:200 (200.0 B)`

Comment: That was eth0 and lo output respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what's working (pinging local IP addresses), you know:

- Your basic network is working properly.
- You are getting a working IP address (via dhcp).
- You are able to communicate on the local subnet (can `ssh` to RPi, can ping router from RPi).

All good news, since you've eliminated a lot of things as the problem (bad cabling, defective hardware). To communicate off the local subnet with IP, your RPi needs to have a properly configured default gateway. Enter the `ip route` command. You should see a line that says `default via <router ip>`. If not, that's likely your problem. Check to make sure your dhcp server (likely your router) is giving out a default gateway with the address lease.

If your routing is correct, you should be able to ping external IP address (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8` for google). If that still doesn't work, it is possible that your router is not forwarding traffic (doing Network Address Translation - NAT) for the RPi, but I'd say this is unlikely since it sounds like other computers can get out.

If you get to where you can ping external addresses by IP address (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`) but not by name (e.g. `ping google.com`), then you have a dns issue. Try using a "known good" dns server such as google's at 8.8.8.8 and try again.

Comment: `ip route` gives `default via "router ip" dev eth0`.

Comment: If your default gateway is set and you're able to ping the IP address of the default gateway, there's not much more you can do on the RPi. You're going to have to look at the router and why it is treating the RPi differently. Presumably your laptop can get out to the Internet, right? Compare the configuration of the RPi and laptop to see if anything obvious is different. What is OS on laptop? Are the laptop and RPi getting IP addresses in the same range? Are the subnet masks the same? I'd take a look at the router settings to see if it's doing any sort of filtering or traffic restrictions.

Comment: Running Ubuntu on laptop with similar IP. Laptop can access internet. Yes it must be some sort of filtering maybe by the mac address.

Answer (score 1):

that address of [my router's ip address 80]is not accurate.  The 80 is probably the port being ID'ed.  Your router's address is probably 192.168.1.1 (for linksys), and these are all INTERNAL addresses, invisible to the internet,(hopefully).
I've found that the lease used in a previous RPi session is probably still registered with the router.  You can check this by entering the router's address into the browser, the credentials window will come up next, then navigate to the DHCP table, usually in the fist tab, and check each device's address connected to your router.
Rather then fudging with the router settings of leasing & releasing, taking a coffee break, after shutting down the RPi & rebooting the router, & letting the router discover the RPi after the reboot, has worked for me!

Comment: I recognise that  IP of 192.168.0.9. Are you using an Edimax product, maybe a Wi-Fi extender....

Comment: Nope that's just the IP my router assigned the pi when I plugged it in.

Comment: Would pulling out power from router and replugging have the same effect? IDK how to reboot. :-)

Comment: That didn't work. Goldilocks suggests its a router issue.

Comment: What type of router please?

Comment: Netgear...what are you looking for specifically?

Comment: The default IP addresses on NETGEAR routers are:
http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1 login with username-admin, password-password; then bring up your DHCP table, it will show you the router assignments (internal IP addresses) for each device connected to your home network.